# JUnit android test classinheritance

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, android-espresso

I have simple Android application with some espresso tests.
I want to write some base class so all of my test classes will inherit its @beforeClass and @afterClass methods, but the problem is when I do it like code example below, JUnit doesn't see any tests at al. I got `Empty test suite.` message. What's the problem?

Code example:

```
public class RealmTest {
    protected static Realm realm;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() {
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        realm.setAutoRefresh(true);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void afterClass() {
        realm.close();
    }
}

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MainActivityTest extends RealmTest {
    @Rule
    public IntentsTestRule<MainActivity> activityTestRule = new IntentsTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void startedFine() {
        assertNotNull(realm);
        onView(withId(R.id.button)).perform(click());
        intended(hasComponent(new ComponentName(getTargetContext(), EducationActivity.class)));
    }
}
```

If I'll run all tests, tests from MainActivityTest won't run.
Thanks for your help, pls say if some additional info is needed.

Comment: put these two methods into MainActivityTest. Are they working

Comment: did you setup `testInstrumentationRunner` in your `app/build.gradle` file

Answer (score 0):

Guessing: the JUnit environment is not looking for **static** methods. So maybe you simply drop that keyword from your base methods (guess you could keep your Realm static nonetheless; I assume you really only want one of those).

But then, another suggestion: don't use inheritance for test cases.

The point that makes test cases **valuable** to you is: they should quickly allow you to find and fix bugs in your production code.

But when your "setup" is hidden from your testcases - because things are not only happening in some @Before method ... but in a @Before method somewhere, in some different class ... well, that can seriously increase the time you will need to understand a failing testcase. Because: instead of just studying your test case, you find yourself digging around within **test code** in order to understand what exactly is happening *besides* the code in that failing test method itself!

Thus: be **really** careful to balancing "code duplication" versus "test case is easy to understand" aspects!

Comment: there are static methods in the base class because methods annotated with @BeforeClass/@AfterClass must be static as JUnit requires it. About the rest, yes, thanks, I agree with you, but I just wanted to do simple initialization here in base class, so I won't repeat the same few lines everywhere, keeping code a bit clean and clear

Comment: Ups; too lang ago that I used that stuff!